# Retaining and retrieving value in a EditText in CustomListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to create a `ListActivity` that has a `CheckBox`, `TextView` and `EditText` in a row in a custom list.

I need to get the user's input in my `EditText` and save that value in a database when the `CheckBox`for that row is selected.  If the `CheckBox`is not selected then the `EditText` is disabled.  The latter I can do, but I'm not able to retain the value of the `EditText` and store it in database.

Currently, if I input anything in `EditText` and press backbutton to minimize the keypad the `EditText` goes back to its previous value.

I have coded the below till now for displaying the custom `ListView` and selecting and unselecting the checkbox. I just need help me with the `EditText` part.

EditExepense.Java

```
package h.pkg.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class EditExpense extends ListActivity {
    int eid, tid, mid;
    String etyp,amount;
    float eamt;
    DBAdapter db;
    ArrayList<Integer> memmid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> memname = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Float> memcexp = new ArrayList<Float>();  
    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button Save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Save);
        //ListView l1= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        setContentView(R.layout.eexp);
        Bundle idata = getIntent().getExtras();
        db = new DBAdapter(this);

        if (idata !=null)
        {
            eid=idata.getInt("EID");
            tid=idata.getInt("TID");
            etyp=idata.getString("ETYP");
            eamt=idata.getFloat("EXAMT");
            amount = "" + eamt;
        }

        try {
            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllmem(tid);
            float nofm = (float)(c.getCount());
            float evenshareamt = eamt/nofm;
            db.close();

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String MN = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                        mid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("MID"));
                        String ceamts = String.valueOf(evenshareamt);

                        list.add(get(MN,ceamts,true));

                        memname.add(MN);
                        memmid.add(mid);
                        memcexp.add(evenshareamt);
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }

            c.close();
        } finally {
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        RadioButton rbs = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Shared);
        RadioButton rbc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Custom);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton rbs = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Shared);

                if (rbs.isChecked()) {
                    //DisplayToast("Option 1 checked!");
                } else {
                    //DisplayToast("Option 2 checked!");
                }
            }
        });
    }    

    public void expUpdate(View V) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    private Model get(String memn, String ceam, boolean sel) {
        return new Model(memn,ceam,sel);
    }
}
```

InteractiveArrayAdapter.Java

```
package h.pkg.main;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView memnames;
        protected EditText ceamount;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.memnames = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.memname1);
            viewHolder.ceamount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.expamt1);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                            boolean isChecked) {
                    Model elementc = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                    elementc.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    boolean edenable = buttonView.isChecked();
                    if(edenable)
                    {
                        viewHolder.ceamount.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder.ceamount.setText("");
                        viewHolder.ceamount.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.memnames.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.ceamount.setText(list.get(position).getCeamt());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Model.Java

```
package h.pkg.main;

public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String ceexpamt;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name, String ceexpamt, boolean selected) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ceexpamt = ceexpamt;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCeamt() {
        return ceexpamt;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCeamt(String ceamt) {
        this.ceexpamt = ceamt;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public void enableEditText()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi All thanks for the answers.. But Since am already using a Model class... I tried to achieve the task done through that example itself... Please see the modified InteractiveArrayAdapter.Java this works fine in retaining the value of the edittext in the correct row after editing.

I have just added this method.. to my InterativeArrayAdapter.java

```
viewHolder.ceamount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (!hasFocus){
                     viewHolder.ceamount.setFocusable(true);
                     Model elemente = (Model) viewHolder.ceamount.getTag();
                     final EditText custamt = (EditText) v;
                     elemente.setCeamt(custamt.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Please see below for the complete code..

```
package h.pkg.main;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView memnames;
        protected EditText ceamount;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.memnames = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.memname1);
            viewHolder.ceamount = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.expamt1);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox1);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Model elementc = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                            elementc.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                            boolean edenable = buttonView.isChecked();
                            if(edenable)
                            {
                            viewHolder.ceamount.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                viewHolder.ceamount.setText("");
                                viewHolder.ceamount.setEnabled(false);
                            }


                        }
                    });

            viewHolder.ceamount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (!hasFocus){
                         viewHolder.ceamount.setFocusable(true);
                         Model elemente = (Model) viewHolder.ceamount.getTag();
                         final EditText custamt = (EditText) v;
                         elemente.setCeamt(custamt.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
            });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.memnames.setTag(list.get(position));
            //viewHolder.memnames.setId(position);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
            //viewHolder.checkbox.setId(position);
            viewHolder.ceamount.setTag(list.get(position));
            //viewHolder.ceamount.setId(position);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).memnames.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).ceamount.setTag(list.get(position));
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.memnames.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.ceamount.setText(list.get(position).getCeamt());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter , use `Map<Integer,Boolean>` and `Map<Integer,String>` to store the status of checkbox and the value of editText

Comment: hi I dont know how to implement that Map.. could u please provide any sample code..

Answer (score 0):

A Map is a link between two data types, so a Map from Integer to Boolean is a one-to-one function from a particular integer value to a corresponding Boolean value ( 1 -> true , 2 -> false etc.) So this would essentially allow you to maintain a "mapping" for each list position to the status of the checkbox. 
The way to implement a Map in java is thus:

```
Map<Integer,Boolean> listMap = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
```

and when you wish to add a mapping from one list element to it's boolean status then you'd have to use this code:

```
listMap.put(yourListPositionInIntValue, statusOfCheckboxInTrueOrFalse);
```

and when you wish to modify the boolean value in the map all you have to do is repeat the above line of code with the same ListPosition and the updated boolean value.